# How to set the file upload path in liferay portlet so that it can be stored either in unix or windows system(machine independent)?

Tags: liferay

The suggestions were giving the path as catalina_home or user/home.
Do I need to set any parameters in server.xml?
And using actionRequest.getPortletSession().getPortletContext().getRealPath("/"); I am unable to store the file path in database.

Comment: Default upload path is temp...But I need to store the files permanently..

Comment: I assume you are not using the Documents and Media API to upload these files. Would that be an option? I haven't used Liferay in a non-windows environment, but I'd assume the pathing would be handled for you.

Comment: Just going through the Doc and Media API..."The APIs can be called from within portlet or non-portlet code. You can make calls to the APIs locally from within the portal or remotely outside of the portal’s Java virtual machine (JVM)"...Does it mean that I can use it when I am not using lportal database?

Comment: Document and Media API is not my option...based on env I have to store the uploaded files in a directory..

Comment: I need to store the files in server...apart from temp folder

Comment: I'm haven't used nor configured a remote setup so I can't comment on that aspect, however, the API stores the files under the `data` directory of the server within a directory dedicated to the API named `document_library`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties properties=PortalUtil.getPortalProperties();

String serverHome = properties.getProperty("liferay.home");
//To get the liferay server home folder

create any folder for uploaded files under it.